# SAPUI5 switch components

Tags: module, components, sapui5

What is the best way to switch between components? For example I have a dashboard component and 2 sub components. How can I switch to this components from the dashboard? I found the method "oComponentContainer.setContainer("componentId");".

Is that the right way to switch to another component?

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar

create the component container

```
this._oContainer = new ComponentContainer(this.createId("CONTAINTER"), {
            handleValidation: true
});
...
```

switch components

```
var oComponent = this.getComponentById(sId, sRelativePathToComponent);
this._oContainer.setComponent(oComponent);
```

retrieve existing component by id or create new one from path, inject in dependencies like a model or event bus

```
getComponentById: function(sId, sCompName) {
    var oComponent = sap.ui.getCore().getComponent(sId);
    if (!oComponent) {
        oComponent = sap.ui.component({
            name: sCompName,
            id: sId,
            componentData: {
                model: this._oModel,
                eventBus: this._oComponent.getEventBus()
            }
        });
    }
    return oComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to Jasper_07's.

On press event to switch to component:

```
...onPressTile: function(oControlEvent){
        var comp = this.oView.oController.getComponent("dashboardCh", oControlEvent.getSource().data("componentName"));
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("dashboardCh", oControlEvent.getSource().data("componentName"));
    }...
```

component handler funtions:

```
/*
     * Component handler
     */
    getComponent: function(channel, componentName){
        var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();

        if(!this.oView.oController.checkComponentExists(channel, componentName)){
            //create component
            var newComp = new sap.ui.getCore().createComponent({    
                name: componentName,
                id: componentName,
                height: "100%"
            });

            //subscripe component
            this.oView.oController.subscripeToEventBus(newComp, channel);
        };

    },

    checkComponentExists: function(_channel, _componentName){
        var componentExists = false;

        if(sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus()._mChannels.dashboardCh != undefined){
            if(_componentName in sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus()._mChannels.dashboardCh.mEventRegistry){
                componentExists = true;
            }
        }

        return componentExists;
    }, 

    subscripeToEventBus: function(newComp, _channel){
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().subscribe(_channel, newComp.getId(), function(){
            sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("compContainer").setComponent(newComp.getId());
        }, this);
    }
```